# How to null check variable of list type using struts2 <s:if> tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, scriptlet, struts-tags

I have list of Payment Gateway retrieved from requestAttribute on my Jsp as below :

```
List<String> payGwList = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("payGwList");
```

I have to populate them in my select-box(combo-box) but before that have to do following check

**EDIT**

> 1. Null Check
> 2. size > 1 Check

My Code is :

```
<%
 <%if(payGwList != null && payGwList.size() > 1){ //edited
%>
    <tr id="paygwrowid" >
    <td width="112" class="content">
        <s:label key="payment.paymentgateway"/><span class="requiredData">*</span>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2" class="content">
        <select name="paymentGateway" id="paymentGateway" class="content" style="width:189px;">
                <option value="0">--Select--</option>
            <%if(payGwList != null && !payGwList.isEmpty()){                    
                for(String paymentGateway : payGwList){  
            %>
                <option value="<%=paymentGateway%>"><%= paymentGateway%></option>                       
            <%}}%>
        </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
<%}%>
```

But how to do achieve the same using `<s:if>` tag as i dont want to use scriptlets on my jsp.

Comment: Scriptlets code should move to the action used to populate the list, then use struts `s:select` tag to display the dropdown.

Answer (score 4):

`<% if(payGwList != null){ %>` =    `<s:if test="payGwList != null">` , while

```
<select name="paymentGateway" id="paymentGateway" class="content" style="width:189px;">
        <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    <%if(payGwList != null && !payGwList.isEmpty()){                    
        for(String paymentGateway : payGwList){  
    %>
        <option value="<%=paymentGateway%>"><%= paymentGateway%></option>                       
    <%}}%>
</select>
```

becomes simply

```
<s:select list = "payGwList"
       listKey = "paymentGateway"
     listValue = "paymentGateway"
     headerKey = "0"
   headerValue = "--Select--"
          name = "paymentGateway" 
            id = "paymentGateway" 
      cssClass = "content" 
      cssStyle = "width: 189px;" 
/>
```

`listValue` and `listKey` are not even necessary here because you are using the same value for both of them.

Avoid Scritplets and be sure to use all the power of the framework through its UI Tags too.

Comment: Sorry Andrea, i have edited my question.is it possible for u to provide the solution for same.

Comment: Yes, but it is useless in this case, because the tag do it for you. `<s:if test="!payGwList.isEmpty()"> ` or `<s:if test="!payGwList.size()>0"> `

Comment: in s:if, not in UI tags (like s:select). The tag already does not print anything (and does not raise errors) if the list is empty.

Comment: Sorry, I did not realized that you was retrieving the List IN THE JSP (inside a Scriptlet). The List must be a property (private List<String> payGwList;) in your Action, with a getter and a setter. Then it will be pushed on the value stack automatically by Struts and it will be available to Struts UI Tags.